# How to configure and run database mail in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, configuration, database-mail

How to enable and run database mail in SQL Server 2008? I know that it need to

- Enabling Service Broker
- Configuring SMTP (a Mail server is needed)
- Using configuration stored procedure

I don't know what's the relation between application and database mail.

Actually how to enable database mail for a **RollBack** and **Commit Transaction** ? (not for all SP , just for some of them)

**Update**: database mail is a service which automatically sends mail (or sms) to a person which you specify in the configuration. You can specify that this event (sending mail) where and when fired. So I want to see how can I configure this.

Comment: Just trying to understand.. you want to send an email when a rollback or commit occurs?

Comment: @Jeff - I've update the question, take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot think of any way to configure db mail to send for every rollback or transaction, that would be a little overkill, and it sounds like you want to be selective about it anyways.

What you can do though is add a call to the email sp after each commit / rollback in your stored procedures. Here's a quick example:

```
BEGIN TRAN
-- sql operations here
COMMIT

-- send email
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'DB Alerts',
@recipients = 'you@yourdomain.com',
@body = 'Commit completed for ...',
@subject = 'SQL Commit/Rollback event';
```

You can read more about the parameters for sp_send_dbmail here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx

Hope this helps